# Why is the solution to this number table what it is?

Tags: mathematics

[image: table of integers]

I know the answer, but I have not yet discovered the path to the answer. Please explain why it is the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the first thing I noticed is that

> all the numbers in the first three columns are cubes. Taking the cube root of all of these numbers gives:
>
>  `2 3 4 72`
>  `1 2 3 18`
>  `5 6 2 ?`

From here, there's not really enough information to get a 100% definitive answer, but the most reasonable one to me is that

> the numbers in the right column are 3 times the product of the numbers to its left, i.e.:
>
>  (2 * 3 * 4) * 3 = 72
>  (1 * 2 * 3) * 3 = 18

Therefore, I propose that your solution is

> (5 * 6 * 2) * 3 = **180**

Comment: Congratulations, your answer is correct. Thank you for the explanation.